# How to Switch to Wifi if LAN internet is not working

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, internet, lan

I am using LUBUNTU.
I need to switch to WIFI internet(if available) if LAN internet is not working.

What I mean is that LAN cable is connected to local router has local ip address.
But Internet is not working.
In this case I need to switch to WIFI network if available.

Please let me know how can it be done?

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: This should work out of the box. If you have LAN and WLAN its likely that OS is using LAN. If LAN fails in terms of a missing cable, there is only WLAN and your Ubuntu installation should use that by itself without user-interaction (at least if the credentials are known)

Comment: If you have a router with LAN and WLAN capabilities, and LAN doesn't work out-of-the-box, it is most likely WLAN won't work either. You need to access your router interface through a web browser. Look in the router manual, find out what your browser's default ip adress is (//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), type that ip in your browser's adress bar (long white strip on window's top) and explore the options. You need to check some of them. Don't know exactly what, don't know your router model and your network setup.

Comment: Did you tried connecting Lubuntu directly to the internet cable? Maybe is a bad router or maybe your internet connection is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a way to do this automatically but if you disconnect the lan cable, WIFI will take over.